# Header disappears on pages with a figure

Tags: header-footer

I noticed that my header (see MWE below) does not show in pages where the figures take up the whole page. Actually, an "irrelevant" header appears which is the section name. In addition, the page numbering is moved from the bottom to the top.

Any help on solving this and making my report look better will be appreciated a lot.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report} 
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{graphics} 
\usepackage{leqno}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{amsthm} 
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{rotating} 
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{floatflt} 
\usepackage{rotating} 
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{floatpag}
\usepackage[left=3cm,top=3cm,right=2.5cm,bottom=2.8cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[authoryear,round]{natbib}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[font={small,it}]{caption}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{2.0} \textwidth=37pc \textheight= 58pc
\oddsidemargin=4pc \evensidemargin=1pc \headsep=15pt
\parindent=1.7pc 
\parskip=0pt
\voffset = -25pt 
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4} 
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{section}{0} 
\def\thesection{\arabic{section}}
\begin{document} 
\chapter{Introduction}\label{Introd.Chap}
\pagestyle{fancy} 
\fancyhf{} 
\rhead{Introduction} 
\lhead{Chapter
\ref{Introd.Chap}} 
\cfoot{\thepage}

\section{This shouldn't appear in the header} Some text \newpage

Some text \newpage

Some text \newpage

\begin{figure} \centering \includegraphics[scale=0.75]{mwe.eps}
\caption{Caption }\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The figure is on a float page, i.e. a page that contains only floats. You have added the package `floatpag` whose purpose is to be able to set the pagestyle for such pages, and by default it sets the pagestyle to `headings`, which is what you see. Hence, just remove `\usepackage{floatpag}`.